# Rendering a Base64 PNG with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, base64

My Node.js server has something that looks like the following:

```
app.get("/api/id/:w", function(req, res) {
    var data = getIcon(req.params.w);
});
```

Here, `data` is a string containing a Base64 representation of a PNG image. Is there any way I can send this to a client accessing the route encoded and displayed as an image (e.g. so the URL can be used in an `img` tag)?

Comment: What kind of image is it? To send it to the client, you'll need to know what content-type the image is (JPEG, PNG, GIF, ICO)?

Comment: It's a PNG; I've edited my question to mention that.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes you can encode your base64 string and return it to the client as an image:

```
server.get("/api/id/:w", function(req, res) {
    var data = getIcon(req.params.w);
    var img = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

   res.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'Content-Length': img.length
   });
   res.end(img); 
});
```

Comment: `var img = new Buffer(data, 'base64');`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I replaced `data.buffer` with `data` as per @lujcon's comment and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely, except that `new Buffer(data, 'base64')` is now deprecated... use `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')` instead

Comment: Thank You! "Content-Length" header was really important to me, otherwise, image was not just loading. Wasted 2 days in it but glad to have found the answer!

Comment: You need to remove the prefix (`data:image\/png;base64`) from the base64 String before Buffering it as image as @JayCrossler explains.

Answer (score 27):

I had to do a bit of manipulation first to get mine in the right format, but this worked great:

```
  var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no third party required!

Comment: You can also use `var base64Data = data.split(',')[1]`

Answer (score 13):

Using "base64-img" component:

```
app.get('/image1', function(req, res) {

  var image1 = 'image1.jpg';

  var base64Img = require('base64-img');
  var imageData1 = base64Img.base64Sync(image1);
  var base64Data = imageData1.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, '');
  var img = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    'Content-Length': img.length
  });
  res.end(img);

});
```