# Posting image binary from NodeJS readFile()

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a form that requires a few fields:

```
<form action="/picUploader.jsp" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="INDIVIDUALID" value="001">
<input type="hidden" name="SYSTEMID" value="J">
<select name="PICTYPEID" size="1">
<option value="-" ></option>
<option value="1" >FRONT</option>
</select>
<input type="file" name="PICTURE">
</form>
```

There is another function that allows users to render an image from TWAIN from the file server, when the user decides to do this, I need to be able to instead of posting the PICTURE field (file picker), send it the image data from the local file and post that through instead.

Here's how I grab the image data from the local file:

```
require("fs").readFile(file, function (err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }

});
```

So how can I, once I grab the data for the local file, post that through along with all the other data in my form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28440633/747579

Comment: So the image gets written in the head as a base64 string and the rest of the stuff gets posted in the body like normal?