# Sending image in response to "get" call on node js server. ( Image is generated from another api call )

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, base64, png

I am using express (node) to make a API call to captcha website which sends me a captcha as png image. Now I am sending that image in response to api call received to my local server. But Image isn't displayed on http://localhost:3000/step1 (configured through express) Instead just a standard failed icon of image is displayed.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

  var options = {
      uri: 'http://image.captchas.net/?client=demo&random=RandomZufall',
      qs: {
          rnd: 0.5 // -> uri + '?access_token=xxxxx%20xxxxx'
      },
      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',

      },

      rejectUnauthorized: false
  };

  rp(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
        res.end(response);

      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          // API call failed...
          res.status(401).send({msg: 'Server Error Occurred'});
      });
});
```

This is screenshot of image received in postman of captca API call.

[image: Postman Captcha API call result]

This is received in my API call
[image: My localhost Api call result]

I have seen and applied versions of these answers
[Rendering a Base64 PNG with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440369/rendering-a-base64-png-with-express)