# Nodejs serve base64 as Image

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to serve a base64 string as an image with `image/png` headers. The headers are being set properly but the images are not being shown all I can see is a blank screen. here is the code:

```
request('someCustomLink', function (error, response, body) {
// someCustomLink gives the base64 string
        var img = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': img.length
        });
        res.end(img);         
});
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440369/rendering-a-base64-png-with-express) is the link that I followed to arrive at this solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here are the response headers from my someCustomLink (it might help in understanding the problem betr)

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:128778
Content-Type:image-jpeg
Date:Thu, 21 Dec 2017 06:03:52 GMT
ETag:"edc04d469779108860478b361b7427d7"
Last-Modified:Mon, 11 Dec 2017 08:54:32 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:QlR39g0vC5CeOo6fdKzX9uFB+uiOtj61c0LKW2rQLcCPWllcKyfbpg93Yido+vZfzMzB3lmhbNQ=
x-amz-request-id:3EC77634D9A05371
```

This is the get req

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });

app.get('/thumb/:thumbLink', function(req, res) {


        request('https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-trybucket/projectImages/'+req.params.thumbLink, function (error, response, body) {
            //console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            //console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            var img = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png'

            });
            res.end(img);
        });
    });
```

-Thanks

Comment: Why are you getting served a base64 PNG? That’s unusual.

Comment: I have an s3 bucket which contains images as base64 PNG.

Comment: Did you try logging `body`?

Comment: Yes tried it. It gives base64 string...

Comment: Here is the link that I am using https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-trybucket/projectImages/e31492f7314837a22a64395eee7cedfd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The response that you are getting contains `data:image/png;base64,`. You have remove this before creating the `Buffer`. See example below

```
request('https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-trybucket/projectImages/e31492f7314837a22a64395eee7cedfd', function(error, response, body) {
    var img = new Buffer(body.split(',')[1], 'base64');
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png',
      'Content-Length': img.length 
    });
    res.end(img);
})
```

Comment: But this Google logo is not base64. I have the customLink serving base64 strings that I need to convert to images. Also tried initializing the request as you told the results are the same all I am seeing is a blank image

Comment: Could you post a functional example?

Comment: added the functioning get req. you can replicate it on your system. find the link in the comment above

Comment: updated the answer. Also remove `.defaults({ encoding: null });`  as suggested earlier.

Comment: `Buffer()` is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the `Buffer.alloc()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`, or `Buffer.from()` methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck for long on this particular issue too only to find out that sending the actual data Body that comes back from s3 is actually sufficient to display the image.
Here's my implementation (in typescript):

```
// a method in my Bucket class

async getObject(key: string) {
    const params = {
      Bucket: this.bucket, //my bucket name set in my constructor
      Key: key,
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        if(data) resolve(data.Body);
      });
    });
  }

// the get request route

app.get(
  "url/:folder/:id",
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { folder, id } = req.params;
    const image = (await new Bucket().getObject(`${folder}/${id}`)) as Buffer;
    res.send(image);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `ECONNRESET` on my server. It turned out that `res.end()` was responsible for it. I replaced it with `res.send()` and the transfer went without problems. Here is my generic solution for serving base64 files

```
async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  //Get the image or file with your own method
  const base64File = await GetBase64File(id)

  const [fileInfo, fileData] = base64File.split(",");
  const contentType = fileInfo.split(";")[0].replace("data:", "");

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
  res.setHeader("Content-Length", fileData.length);

  const buffer = Buffer.from(fileData, "base64");
  res.send(buffer);
};
```