# Return image from Node REST API and use in img.src on client-side

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am storing images in MongoDB as base64 string. I created Express route to get image by id:

```
router.get('/:userId/images/:imgId', (req, res) => {
  Image.findOne(
    { _id: req.params.imgId },
    (err, img) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('someErr');
      } else {
        var resultImg = Buffer.from(img.data, 'base64');
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'image/png',
          'Content-Length': resultImg.length
        });
        res.end(resultImg);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Client-side:

```
<img src={`api/users/${userId}/images/${imgId}`} />
```

What I am sure about:

1. path is correct, server receives request and returns 200 response
2. data is correctly fetched from MongoDB
3. base64 string is correct (when I copy paste to verifier like https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, it is working)

Why images are not loaded?

Comment: try changing `res.end(resultImg)` to  `res.end(resultImg, 'binary');`

Comment: @Amirmasudzarebidaki it doesn't help

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47918659/8247278) answer? Doesn't it helped?

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the output has this string at the beginning

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,your base 64 goes here'/>
```

you can test by copying the output and put it in a static html and see does it work.
 so may be something like this would help

```
<img src=`data:image/png;base64,{`api/users/${userId}/images/${imgId}`}`/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try hit your backend using AJAX or Fetch API ?
After that, you can load response from that API into your image element

Comment: You can check this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/zzarcon/1a3603b84dac7abe5e3f/raw/7c0e23db42d79edb62b8e88cc3eef0654c371f8b/fetch_blob.js)