# How to find length of a stream in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-streams

I have a function call `uploadStream(compressedStream)` in my code where I am passing `compressedStream` as a parameter to the function but before that I need to determine the length of the `compressedStream`.
Does anyone know how can I do that in NodeJS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js: determine length of stream before it is piped to final destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008318/node-js-determine-length-of-stream-before-it-is-piped-to-final-destination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get length by getting stream chunks length on the "data" event

```
compressedStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
   console.log('Got %d characters of string data:', chunk.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
            let size = 0
            compressedStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
              size = size + chunk.length
            })
            compressedStream.on('end', () => {
              console.log(size)
            })
```